# Rbind data returned by a shiny module to a reactiveValues object

Tags: r, shiny

I am using shiny modules in my app which return data to the main app. This data then should be rbinded to an existing data.frame stored in a reactiveValues object.

Simplified not working example:

```
library(shiny)

data <- data.frame(x = 1:10)

moduleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns("append"), "Append row")
}

module <- function(input, output, session) {
  values2 <- reactiveValues(new_row = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$append, {
    values2$new_row <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 1))
  })
  return(values2$new_row)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  moduleUI("mod"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues(data = data)

  x <- callModule(module, "mod")

  observeEvent(x, {
    values$data <- rbind(values$data, x)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    values$data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Replace `return(values2$new_row)` by `return(reactive({values2$new_row}))` in your `module` function and `x` by `x()` in the `observeEvent` inside your `server` side.

You can a working example [here](https://gustav.shinyapps.io/R-Module-Reactive/) :

```
library(shiny)

options(shiny.error=recover)

data <- data.frame(x = 1:10)

moduleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns("append"), "Append row")
}

module <- function(input, output, session) {

  values2 <- reactiveValues(new_row = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$append, {

    values2$new_row <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 1))
  })

  return(reactive({values2$new_row}))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  moduleUI("mod"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues(data = data)

  x <- callModule(module, "mod")

  observeEvent(x(), {
    values$data <- rbind(values$data, x())
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    values$data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

If you want to understand how I got to the above, see the following:

When running your code, we get the following message:

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
  61: stop
  60: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
  59: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
  58: $.reactivevalues
  56: module [#10]
  51: callModule
  50: server [#5]
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

This says that we are having problems in line 5 of the `server` function (the line with `x <- callModule(module, "mod")`) and line 10 of the `module` function (the line with `return(values2$new_row)`).

Putting `browser()` in line 9 of the `module` function and running the code again makes the browser stops right before `return(values2$new_row)`. Running this piece of code in browser yields the error message:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

This means that whatever you are returning should be inside a reactive or part of an observe function. So, we write `return(reactive({values2$new_row}))` and hit enter to see that this works (i.e. it doesn't give any error and our debugger goes to line 10 of the `module` function).

Typing Q and hitting enter to leave browser mode and get back to our code. Put the correct code `return(reactive({values2$new_row}))`.

But that's not all. Because our function is now returning a reactive value, we have to call `x` using `x()`. So, changing this in the `observeEvent` bit yields:

```
  observeEvent(x(), {
    values$data <- rbind(values$data, x())
  })
```